# How to see memory's manufacture date?

Tags: hardware, devices, dmidecode, memory-card

I bought new memory for my Thinkpad.

Some Windows softwares can tell me the memory's **manufacturer** and **date**. Is there any Linux software that can do that?

`dmidecode -t memory` and `lshw -class memory` tell me the vendor, product number, serial number. How can I find out manufacture date?

Answer (score 0):

> Some Windows softwares can tell me the memory's manufacturer and date.

Probably not from the actual module and likely uses an internal database or does a look-up on the net.

Most memory modules do not have a manufacturer's name. If there was `dmidecode --type memory` would show a "Manufacturer" with the name.

1. Use the value of "Part number" for a google search (KP223C-ELD is Kingston)
2. Another option:

   ```
   decode-dimms | grep -i manuf
   ```

   It does it with an [internal list](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools/+/refs/heads/master/eeprom/decode-dimms) too.

3.Found a [list](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/39268/jep106k.pdf) and it looks the same as at #2.